# On the wikipedia entry for Borel-Moore homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

The wikipedia page on Borel-Moore homology claims to give several definitions of it,
all of which are supposed to coincide for those spaces $X$ which are homotopy equivalent to a finite CW complex and which admit a sufficiently nice embedding into a smooth manifold.

My question concerns one of the definitions on that page: it is asserted that if $X$ is a space and $\bar X$ is some compactification, then there is a definition of Borel-Moore homology given by
$$
H_*^{\text{BM}}(X) := H_*(\bar X,\bar X \setminus X) .
$$
The entry additionally requires that the pair $(\bar X,X)$ should be a CW pair for this to work.

**It then goes on to assert that $\bar X = X^+$, the one-point compactification, will suffice for this.**

Frankly, **I don't see how $(X^+,X)$ will form a CW pair in most instances.** For example suppose $X = \Bbb Z$ is the set of integers which is considered as a discrete space. Then in this instance $(X^+,X)$ certainly fails to be a CW pair.

Another example: $X = S^1 \setminus \ast$ with one point compactification $S^1$. Then
$(S^1,S^1 \setminus \ast)$ is not a CW pair either.

**My Questions:**

*(1) For what class of spaces $X$ does
$H_*(X^+,+)$ coincide with definition of Borel-Moore homology given by locally finite chains?*

*(2) Does the wikipedia entry contain a mistaken assumption? Perhaps we do not need to assume that $(X^+,X)$ can be given the structure of a CW pair?*

Note: if $X = \Bbb Z$ and if we use the above as a definition of Borel-Moore homology  then
$
H_0^{\text{BM}}(X) 
$
is a free abelian group whose generators are given by the underlying set of $\pi_0(X) = \Bbb Z$. This is clearly the wrong answer: it should be the countably infinite cartesian product of copies of the integers indexed over $X$ instead (using, say, the definition of Borel-Moore homology given by locally finite chains).

**Another Question:**

*(3) Is there a definition the above kind (using compactifications) 
which will work (i.e., coincide with the locally finite chain definition)
 for $X = \Bbb Z$?*

(I suspect not, since ordinary singular homology in degree zero is always free abelian.)

Incidentally, later in the page it lists the main variance property: Borel-Moore homology is supposed to be covariant with respect to proper maps. The page gives a
proof using the above definition. But since the above definition doesn't work in general, I don't see how this is really supposed to be a proof.

Comment: Maybe there is some language confusion here, but doesn't "finite CW-complex" mean a CW-complex with finitely many cells (that is, both finite-dimensional and finite type)?  So how would $X=\mathbb{Z}$ (with the discrete topology) fit in that context?

Comment: What is your exact question concerning BM-homology?

Comment: Andre & Alex:  What is presented above is claimed on the wikipedia page to be a definition of Borel-Moore homology. But, I don't know of any reasonable assumptions on $X$ which would make $(X^+,X)$ into a CW pair. I'd like to know what the correct assumptions on such $X$s are for this definition to be valid. The wikepedia entry is not precise about the assumptions.

Comment: Alex: it is not asserted in the definition that X needs to be a finite complex. It is claimed that X needs to have additional properties (homotopy type of a finite complex and have a good embedding into a manifold) to get all the variant definitions to agree. My question is what assumptions do we need to make on $X$ for the above definition to be valid. I cannot for the life of me imagine that $(X^+,X)$ is going to be a CW pair even if $X$ is a fairly reasonable space (I could be wrong).

Comment: For example, why should $(S^1,S^1 - \ast)$ be a CW pair? it doesn't look to me like the inclusion $S^1 - \ast \to S^1$ is a subcomplex.

Comment: @JohnKlein, if you are looking for a good treatment of locally finite singular or cellular homology, then obviously this Wikipedia page is not a very good source. I recommend instead taking a look at Chapters 3, 4 and Appendix A of Ranicki's _Ends of Complexes_ (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/ends.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Igor. I'm familiar with (Hughes' and) Ranicki's work. But they don't give a comparison of the various definitions. They are content to give two definitions: one the locally finite singular theory and the other a cellular version.

Comment: @John: Perhaps you could add the details you stated in the comments to your question? As it stands, it is not entirely clear what you are asking from the question alone.

Comment: In particular, it would help to insert the question "what assumptions do we need to make on X for the above definition to be valid?"

Comment: @Ricardo and Scott: I did what you suggested.

Comment: Although $(S^1,S^1\setminus\ast)$ is not a CW pair, it has the homotopy type of one: triangulate $S^1$ on the complement of a tiny neighborhood around the missing point, and then add the vertex-at-infinity. Everything works out in an up-to-homotopy way, so perhaps the only issue is requiring $(X^+,X)$ to have the homotopy type of a CW pair. Perhaps a general scheme would involve cofibrant replacements of $X \hookrightarrow X^+$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Chriss & Ginzburg](http://books.google.com/books?id=lwS59rR78eIC&dq=chriss+and+ginzburg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mkH3UbavFZal4AP1m4DgAw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA), it's asserted that the Borel-Moore homology is given by $H_*(\bar X, \bar X\setminus X)$ if $\bar X$ is the one-point compactification **or** any compactification such that the inclusion is cellular.  They very pointedly do not assume that the inclusion of $X$ into $X^+$ is cellular.  They reference [Bredon](http://books.google.com/books?id=zGdqWepiT1QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=bredon+sheaf+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gkP3UcPnOKT-4APamoHQBQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage) but don't cite a particular chapter.

Comment: Ben: I guess you mean that $\bar X \setminus X \to \bar X$ should be cellular. That's a reasonable condition, provided a cell structure on $\bar X$ is given. It seems then that the wikipedia entry has an error then.

Comment: Ben: I just checked Chriss & Ginzburg. It is clear now that the wikipedia entry has a mistake.

Comment: I took the liberty to correct the wikipedia page.

Comment: Another reference (with Google Books preview available) is "Representation Theories and Algebraic Geometry" http://books.google.pl/books?id=Q0Nyon7-qDMC , pp. 129-130