# When is the one-point compactification well-pointed?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, compactifications

This is a follow up to my previous
[question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138117/on-the-wikipedia-entry-for-borel-moore-homology).

**Question:**

*Is there a reasonably natural set of conditions which guarantee that the one-point 
compactification $X^+$ of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ is well-pointed?*

(Where, of course, the basepoint I'm referring to is the point at $\infty$.)

Comment: I added the tag 'gn.general-topology'. Feel free to remove it if you don't think it applies. The tag 'gt.geometric-topology' may also be relevant (but may not be *directly* applicable).

Comment: Oh, that's fine. The more tags the merrier.

Comment: Have you seen the 1978 paper "Homotopy properties of LC spaces at infinity - smoothness and calmness" by Zvonko Cerin? It's been a while, but I think a more general question is answered there: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.pjm/1102805986.

Comment: @ViditNanda: I looked at the paper you suggested, but I am not a shape theorist, so I couldn't make any sense of it. The only statement I could understand was the acknowledgement: "We completed this work during compulsory military service at Military High School in Belgrade. We thank superior officers for providing conditions stimulating research." Could you please tell me where I would find the answer to my question in this paper?

Comment: Here is an example which I find counter-intuitive, and may be interesting to keep in mind. The [Whitehead manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold) is a space with a highly non-trivial topology at infinity whose one-point compactification is nevertheless well-pointed. See [this answer by Sergey Melikhov](http://mathoverflow.net/a/87678/21095) for an explanation.

Comment: I believe a necessary condition is that the space of ends must be discrete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_a_space

Comment: I just looked again at Hughes & Ranicki's book. It seems that they give an answer in their setting: Prop 7.11 states that a "forward tame" ANR $W$ has the homotopy type of a based CW complex.

Comment: @John: Forward tameness appears to be a useful condition. Nevertheless, I was hoping for a more general criterion. For example, the Whitehead manifold I mentioned above is *not* forward tame.